# MyBatis: Select a Map to map

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

How can I select a map of map using mybatis?

```
SELECT process_code, priority, execution_interval FROM scheduling_parameter
```

How can I retrieve a result in the form
`Map<process_code, Map<priority,execution_interval>>`

Answer (score 2):

I think you implements the mybatis ResultHandler and write your transform code in it; or get map from mybatis and write the transform code in your service class.
like this:

```
sqlSession.select("yourstatmentid",new ResultHandler(){ 
    @Override 
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context){ 
        List<Map> data = (List<Map>) context.getResultObject(); 
        //transform list to map as you like 
    } 
 })
```

Comment: Any kind of example would help, a reference, or a few lines of code.

Comment: just like this > sqlSession.select("yourstatmentid",new ResultHandler(){
            @Override
            public void handleResult(ResultContext context){
               List<Map> data = (List<Map>) context.getResultObject();
                //transform list to map as you like
            }
        }
        })

Comment: You would be more likely to get an upvote if you put the example in your answer, help people read it. Format it as code. That was my point, only to help you.

Comment: thanks very much, I was confused how to format code in comment, forget that I can edit the answer.

Comment: @Persia Thanks for the answer. I did the same, I obtained a List of Map and iterated to generate the required result. I was wondering if there is anything built in with mybatis, like SqlSession.selectMap. Can we use selectMap with some how configuring the resultMap to return a Map of map?